# Logic Error sampling distribution of proportions

Tags: pandas, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, statistics

The problem states the following: A sample of 200 pieces has been taken, 10 % of produced units are not working ¿What's the probability that i / 200 pieces don't work?
Where i is an integer that takes numbers from 1 to 100

I tried to solve this, using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from scipy.stats import norm
n = 200
prob = []
not_working = []
for i in range(1,201):
    #I take the data given in the problem
    p = i / 200 
    P = 0.10
    Q = 1-P

    # I take Z value to compute area under the curve 
    z_value = (p-P) / (np.sqrt((P*Q) / n))

    # Area under the curve is the probability of having i not working pieces
    area_under_curve = norm.cdf(z_value)*100
    
    not_working.append(i)
    prob.append(area_under_curve)

#Plot The probability of having i not working pieces

sns.lineplot(x=not_working,y=prob)
plt.xlabel('Number of not working pieces')
plt.ylabel('Probability')
plt.show()
```

The problem here is that the plot shows that over 30 until 200 pieces, the probability that they ALL don't work is 100% and this doesn't make sense.

Comment: You should probably be using the binomial distribution, not the normal. Normal is going to be a poor approximation for binomial for less than 30 trials, and when p is close to 0 or 1, both of which apply here.

Comment: What's the exact definition of what they want you to compute? Are they asking for the probability that you have i broken parts or more? Are they asking for the probability that you have i broken parts or less? Or are they asking for the probability that you have *exactly* i broken parts? The three of those will give you different answers.